# MVC 3 Beta /  Razor / Windows 2003  issue

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, iis, razor, publish

I'm trying to publish and view a simple MVC3 Beta Razor application. I am able to publish the site via filesystem with no problems onto my Windows 2003/IIS6 server.  When I attempt to access the the website with a browser, i receive the following error message:

> Attempt by method 'System.Web.WebPages.Razor.WebPageRazorHost.get_GlobalAsaxTypeName()' to access method 'System.Web.Compilation.BuildManager.GetGlobalAsaxType()' failed.

I can publish the default project MVC3 Beta ASPX view engine app, and I am able to view the website. If I switch the engine to Razor, it will fail as above.  Any ideas?

Comment: Can you post the full stack trace of the error? This type of error is easier to diagnose with that information.

Answer (score 1):

I resolved the problem.  To my suprise, the server was running .NET 4 RC1